# Cannot access Google Places API with generated Key

Tags: ios, google-places-api, google-places

I have generated an API Key using google's console for my project. Then as they have mentioned in their documentation, I have added the key in my applications `AppDelegate` in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. The following code:

```
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"{MY_API_KEY}"];
```

Then I used the following code to send a Google Places Auto complete request from inside my ViewController:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                    initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=%@&sensor=false&key={MY_API_KEY}",searchString]]
                                    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                    timeoutInterval:120];
    placesListConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

And I am getting the following response:

```
{
   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.",
   "predictions" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? How to rectify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved the issue. Instead of using `API_KEY` for IOS, i created an `API_KEY` for web that doesn't need a referrer and then sent the request using that key. Now it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked Developers Console?  Is Places API enabled under APIs & auth > APIs?